# Trying to use Debug.WriteLine to view what is being written to port. Getting error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Tags: c#, debugging

This is what it looks like so far:
The error is on line 31 "Debug.WriteLine(writeToPort);" Im basically want to see the data structure that is being sent over port

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Stopwatch watch { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            port.Open();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            writeToPort(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            Debug.WriteLine(writeToPort);
        }

        public void writeToPort(Point coordinates)
        }

           port.Write(String.Format("X{0}Y{1}",
               (coordinates.X / (Size.Width / 180)),
               (coordinates.Y / (Size.Height / 180))));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WriteToPort` is a metod that does not return a value. You can't `Debug.WriteLine` a method. If you want to output the structure, do so by writing the individual values, and do it within `WriteToPort` instead of `MouseMove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Debug.WriteLine` accepts a `string`. You are giving it a method. Since you don't have `()` on the method, it's not *calling* the method and using the return value, but you're passing a reference to the method itself, which doesn't work with `Debug.WriteLine`.

But `writeToPort` doesn't return a `string` either, so you just can't use it there.

If you want to see what was sent over the port, then you need to save what you're sending in its own variable and print that to the debug console. You can do it all in `writeToPort`, like this:

```
public void writeToPort(Point coordinates)
{
    var stringToWrite = String.Format("X{0}Y{1}",
       (coordinates.X / (Size.Width / 180)),
       (coordinates.Y / (Size.Height / 180)))
    port.Write(stringToWrite);
    Debug.WriteLine(stringToWrite);
}
```